# Is there any Filter condition for string "contains" in MS Graph API V1.0

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to find users in Department :

```
string searhString="IT Admin Onsite";

var departmentPeoples = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter($"department eq '{searchString}'").Select(u => new {
                        u.DisplayName,
                        u.MobilePhone,
                        u.BusinessPhones,
                        u.UserPrincipalName
                    }).GetAsync();
```

But, i want to search all Department which contains ,hence my searchString will be

string searhString="Admin";

I have tries startswith ,but that will work only when my searchString is "IT" in the given example code. 
How to achieve this Task?

Please Help.

Comment: Did you try substringof?

Comment: @baywet i checked, substringof doesn't work.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid that `contains` is not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter).

> Note: The following $filter operators are not supported for Azure AD
>   resources: ne, gt, ge, lt, le, and not. The contains string operator
>   is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

Currently you could get all the results and filter with the Department in your C# code.

Answer (score 3):

I believe @Allen Wu's answer to this may be outdated. According to this documentation contains appears to be generally supported, but it varies from endpoint to endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

Comment: It's 2022 now, and no, `contains` is still not supported on `User`'s properties. For example:

var users3 = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request(new Option[] { new QueryOption("$count", "true")}).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual").Filter("contains(displayName, 'one')").GetAsync();

Will throw error :

Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Operator: 'Contains' is not supported.